Multivariable Chain Rule notation on Implicit equation
In my Introduction to Diferential Multivariable Calculus class we have proven the Chain Rule theorem, that says:
Given an open set $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $a \in D$, and $f:D \to \mathbb{R}^m$ a diferentiable function in $a$. Suppose that $f(D) \subset E$ is another open, and that $f:E \to \mathbb{R}^p$ is diferentiable at $f(a)$. Then the composition is diferentiable at a, and it follows that $D(g \circ f)(a) = D(g(f(a)) \circ D(f(a))$, where $D(F)$ is the jacobian matrix of the function $F$.
Now, my question is in the notation used. In the theorem of the Existence Of the Implicit Function, there's a use of the Chain Rule that I can't understant: given $F(g(x),x)=0$, where $F:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (the function is not important here), we can obtain because of the Chain Rule the following relation:
$$D_y(F(g(x),x))D(g(x)) + D_zF(g(x),x))=0,$$ where $D_yF= \frac{\delta(F_1,\cdots,F_n)}{\delta(y_1,\cdots,y_n)}$ is the jacobian matrix, and same for $D_zF$ ($y,z$ are vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^p$).
I tried to use the theorem and the given notation, and I try to multiply the jacobians, but I think I'm getting lost on the notation used.
Can someone explain in detail how the equation is derived from the Chain rule?

View the map $x\mapsto {g(x)\choose x}$ as going from $\mathbb R^p$ to $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^p,.$ Its Jacobian is a block matrix that you multiply with the Jacobian of $F,.$

That's what I thought, because then it would made sense that there's the Identity being multiplied. However, if $x \to x$ is the identity, then we could decompose any jacobian matrix with $D_y + D_z$, but that doesn't make any sense to me. They aren't event the same dimension, right?

Do not mechanically manipulate symbols. Come up with a low dimensional concrete example to see the matrices in action.

In implicit function case that prompted you to set up this post we don't calculate the Jacobian of $F(id(x),id(x)),.$ Go back to my first comment and restart.

Then, let $h(x): \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^{n+p}$, by $(g(x),x)$. Then $D(F \circ h)= D(F \circ h)D(h)$. But $D(h)= \begin{pmatrix} D(g(x)) \ D(x) \end{pmatrix}$, and $D(F \circ h)= (\frac{\delta F_1, \cdots, F_n}{\delta x_1,\cdots,x_n},\frac{\delta F_1, \cdots, F_n}{\delta x_{n+1},\cdots,x_p})$. Then we multiply the block matrixes and we get the result. Thanks
